# Echo php variable inside of p tag, returns outside of the p tag

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using WordPress and I thought this advanced custom field would output `the_field('price')` inside of the `p` tag however it output's it before the `p` tag and not inside it. Thanks ahead of time.

```
<?php
    echo "<p> Tickets Start at CA$" . the_field('price') . "</p>"; 
?>
```

This is what it looks like in html

[image]

Comment: i remember this question from before, i have the same guess, that you never followed up on `the_field()` has an echo

Comment: Oh shit your right, I feel dumb now

Comment: you should accept the answer in the original question and delete this one

Comment: Ok will do, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
<?php
    echo "<p> Tickets Start at CA$" . get_field('price') . "</p>";
?>
```

The reason why you might be having issues is because `the_field()` prints the value using `echo`, so the code sample in your question ends up being equivalent to this:

```
<?php
    echo "<p> Tickets Start at CA$" . echo get_field('price') . "</p>";
?>
```

Reference: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/#overview

Comment: The second code block won't work because `echo` is a language construct. But you can just wrap the 2nd echo inside a function to demonstrate the effect. I.e. https://3v4l.org/XaCIM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
<p> Tickets Start at CA$ <?=the_field('price') ?></p>
```